# pagination or search lost value batchedit

Tags: asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I want when i edit value in batch edit i don't like to lost the value edited.
how can i fix this issue.The problem is when i edit in batch and i search row or pagination it lost the value edited.
can someone help me how fix it.**Losing Batch Editing Changes on Paging or any other PostBack**
The data displayed typically has multiple pages of data; currently, editing data on a page and then trying to switch to another page without clicking "Save changes" warns the users that the changes haven't been saved.

**How can redirect pagination to save changes before to pagination**

Answer (score 0):

From - [GridView - How to implement Batch Editing with multiple pages](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T153775)

> The only solution for this task is to implement a temporary data
> source that will contain all user changes made in GridView until the
> Save Changes button is clicked.

References:
[ASPxGridView in Batch Editing Mode - Unsaved changes are not discarded when the ShowConfirmOnLosingChanges option is disabled](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q571990)
[ASPxGridView in Batch Edit mode - How to set a custom 'leave page' message](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T104558)

Hope this help.

Comment: i found the two properties:BatchEditStartEditing and BatchEditEndEditing  how can i use it to redirect it to BatchEditingcontroller